# Error: "Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'" when importing module built by webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

I have built Angular2 (RC6) module using Webpack (tried both 1.x and 2.x) and published to npm but when I import this module as a dependency to my `AppModule` (imports section) I am getting this runtime error.

If I build using `tsc` command then I am not getting this error. I need Webpack because I have html and css files which should be bundled into `js` file.

Also everything works fine if I build all my modules in a single bundle.

My webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: './index.ts',
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    resolve: {
      root: [ path.join(__dirname, 'src') ],
      extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.ts$/, loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader'] },
          { test: /\.(html|css)$/, loader: 'raw-loader' }
        ]
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?